# How do I discover property names?

Tags: entities, migrations

When doing a custom D7 to D8 migration, i sometimes need to migrate a specific value such as 'fid' (for example file ID of an images) into the

```
'field_image/target_id'
```

property. How do I find out which property i can use for D8 fields? By property i mean the `target_id` part. For example for `uid` field? The devel module does not seem to be helpful here, or I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [EntityFieldManager](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/8.3.x). This is an example how to get the properties for the field `uid` of the entity `node`:

```
$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions('node');
$properties = $fields['uid']->getPropertyDefinitions();
```

From the command line you can use this in a `drush php-eval` command:

```
drush ev "var_dump(\Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions('node')['uid']->getPropertyDefinitions())"
```